# How can you use general variables in classes which do not have that variable as an instance field?

Tags: java, oop

This question is about OOP in general, but I'm programming in Java.

My class `Game`, which manages the program, has some objects as variables, which are used in nearly every method in every class. However, neither of them has access to each other. How can I still use them in their methods?

An oversimplified example is that I have 3 classes: `Game`, which is the main class managing everything, `Enemy`, and `Player`. All enemy methods need to know where the player is to shoot in the right direction and all player methods need to know the enemy's state to figure out when he got hit. So how can I save these objects (`player` and `enemy`) so each of them has access to each other?

I thought about using "global" variables as in static ones, but many users said that they shouldn't be used (for some reason).

Are there alternatives? Right now I'm using Processing which does have global variables but I'm thinking about using another engine.

Comment: A usecase would help answering the question.

Comment: You could pass the player and world as an argument to the method you want to call.

Comment: @DanielJacob That is an option, but as I said nearly every method needs to have access to the main objects (and there are a few of them). Passing everything as arguments to every method seems a bit much. Maybe I could put all objects in another object and pass that one as a required argument? This seems reasonable

Comment: @saurabhgupta I've added an example in the question

Answer (score 0):

you make getters and setters for `Enemy` and `Player` classes variables and create a fourth class (something like `EnemyPlayerInteraction`) which has access to both `Enemy` and `Player` and manages their mutual states

Comment: But how would `Enemy` have access to `Player` through `EnemyPlayerInteraction`? Wouldn't it be easier to just tediously pass `Player` as an argument to every method of `Enemy`?

Comment: that depends on your architecture. If you do not wanna have Player and Enemy just as POJOs, but want them to contain also funtionality, then passing Player to Enemy methods as argument is an option. But not a good design IMO. I'd prefer to have all the functional methods outside, e.g. in EnemyPlayerInteraction

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve this by the `has-a relationship` which also called aggregation.
See the following example.

```java
public class Game{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    
    }
}

class Location{
    int x;
    int y;
} 

class Enemy{
    Player player;
    Location location;
    
    public Enemy(Player player){
        this.player = player;
    }
    
    public void Shoot(){
        Location playerLocation = this.player.location;
        // shoot logic
    }
}

class Player{
    Enemy emeny;
    Location location;
    
    public Player(Enemy enemy){
        this.enemy = enemy;
    }
    
    public void FindEnemy(){
        Location enemyLocation = this.enemy.location;
        // enemy find logic
    }
}
```

You can have an enemy instance in player and player instance in an enemy so that you can access the location of the enemy from the player class and location of the player from enemy class.

For more interesting design:

You can have a list of enemies inside the player class and write a method to add enemies into the list (maybe when an enemy comes near to the player location).

This is just a simple example of how you can solve your problem. But when you developing the game in the advanced way you have to use more tools and concepts in order to do this like it's not a good idea to store all the enemies inside the list of a player. You can use some other data sources for that.

Comment: Your last paragraph is what I asked. My actual program is significantly more complex (around 15 of these variables), so storing them in each class is not an option. My example was just a rough structure of my code to show what I want to do. I think I'm gonna solve this problem by having an object with all these variables which is passed down as an argument

Answer (score 0):

I am making a few assumptions:

1. Enemies are Spawned (i.e they are created after the player is instantiated)
2. Enemies use the player location to shoot/face/advance at the player
3. Player takes a list of Enemies (say to cycle through available targets in an auto aim mode).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Game{

    public void start(){
        Player player = new Player();
        Enemy enemy1 = new Enemy(player);
        Enemy enemy2 = new Enemy(player);
    }
}

class Player {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    // Contains a list of enemies in the line of sight.
    private List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    // when a new enemy appears.
    public void registerEnemy(Enemy enemy){
        enemies.add(enemy);
    }



}

class Enemy {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Player player;

    public Enemy(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
        player.registerEnemy(this);
    }

    // A method that makes the enemy face the or move towards player.
    public void acquireTarget() {
        int player_x = player.getX();
        int player_y = player.getY();

        if (findRelativeDistance(player_x, player_y) < 100.00){
            // Do something to move towards player.
        }
    }

    // Function that finds the distance of the enemies current position to given co-ordinate.

    public double findRelativeDistance(int x, int y){
        // Logic to calculate distance.
    }
}
```

Now depending on the complexity of the actual game logic, this naive implementation may not be sufficient.

There are many useful design pattern that can be applied to elegantly tackle different scenarios. I think as you are designing a game it might be worthwhile to explore **state design pattern**, **observer design pattern** etc.